# How do I call a color picker when a button is pressed in android?

Tags: android, button, colors

The button has a predefined color. I need to show a selection of colors on pressing the button. And then give the button the selected background color. I have just started android programming. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a color picker for this purpose.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

 void onClick(View v) {
// create the color picker dialog and display it.
ColorPickerDialog dlg = new ColorPickerDialog(v.getContext(),new OnColorChangedListener()     {
      void colorChanged(int color) {
           mSelectedColor = color;
       }

   }),initialColor);
   dlg.show();
  }
});
```

initialColor will be replaced by mSelectedColor, the new selected color from the picker.